# What is the best way to associate a table entry with either one or two relations, and query per-entry OR per-relation?

Tags: database-design, sqlalchemy

I have a table of members with SQLalchemy in Python (on top of MySQL), and each member has exactly one or two attributes.

I need to be able to select a list of members:

| Member | Attributes |
| --- | --- |
| First | 1 |
| Second | 1, 2 |

I need to be able to select a list of members, but with duplicate-ish entries by attribute:

| Member | Attribute |
| --- | --- |
| First | 1 |
| Second | 1 |
| Second | 2 |

Members are added not with a multiple-choice attribute selector, but with a one-select dropdown with specified options: "1", "1, 2", "2", etc

I've thought of a few ways to do this:

1. Create a Member table, and join table, and a Division table. To get the second table, use the join table (easy to implement, might be excessive, and requires some handling on member creation. It would also allow illegal combinations, but that can have catches in code)
2. Create a Member table and a Attribute enum, which only allows the specified combinations. Getting the second table where each row has one attribute would need extra logic.

I am preferring the first. Which is the better choice, or is there a third choice better than either of the above?

Comment: Define "better". Then, how are you stuck evaluating that for yourself? [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to assign attributes to users, and respect normalization forms is:

**Members table**

- memberid, primary key
- other fields for members...

**Attributes table**

- attributeid, primary key
- other fields for attributes

**Member-Attribute link table**

- memberid, foreign key to table members, non-null
- attributeid, foreing key to attributes table, non-null

When you build your interface and want a drop down selection, build your select options by querying the attributes table.

This is the most flexible way to do it.  If you need to add attributes later, you will not have to modify any code, just add a new attribute with new id.  It also allows you to build your queries once and for all.  A simple

```
SELECT memberid
FROM member-attribute
WHERE attributeid = <SOME ID>
```

and these will always be valid, even if your attributes change in the future.

Using enums, while possible, makes evolution and updates more complicated (experienced first hand).